# Hash value from keys on Cassandra

Tags: hash, cassandra, key, hector, partitioner

I'm developing a mechanism for Cassandra using Hector. 
What I need at this moment is to know which are the hash values of the keys to look at which node is stored (looking at the tokens of each one), and ask directly this node for the value. What I understood is that depending on the partitioner Cassandra uses, the values are stored independently from one partitioner to other. So, are the hash values of all keys stored in any table? In case not, how could I implement a generic class that once I read from System Keyspace the partitioner that is using Cassandra this class could be an instance of it without the necessity of modifying the code depending on the partitioner? I would need it to call the getToken method to calculate the hash value for a given key.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to do - Cassandra handles all of the hash values internally using the partitioner. What are you trying to do with them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally after testing different implementations I found the way to get the partitioner using the next code:

```
            CqlQuery<String, String, String> cqlQuery = new CqlQuery<String, String, String>(
            ksp, StringSerializer.get(), StringSerializer.get(),   StringSerializer.get());
            cqlQuery.setQuery("select partitioner from local");
            QueryResult<CqlRows<String, String, String>> result = cqlQuery.execute();
            CqlRows rows = result.get();
            for (int i = 0; i < rows.getCount(); i++) {
                RowImpl<String, String, String> row = (RowImpl<String, String, String>) rows
                .getList().get(i);
                List<HColumn<String, String>> column = row.getColumnSlice().getColumns();
                for (HColumn<String , String> c: column) {
                    System.out.println(c.getValue());
            }

    }
```

Answer (score 2):

Hector's CqlQuery is poorly supported and buggy.  You should use the native Java CQL driver instead: https://github.com/datastax/java-driver

Comment: For those seeing this and the other answer from jbellis to this question: these duplicates appear because I merged another question into this one.

Answer (score 1):

You could just reuse the partitioners defined in Cassandra: https://github.com/apache/cassandra/tree/trunk/src/java/org/apache/cassandra/dht and then using the token ranges you could do the routing.

Answer (score 1):

The [CQL driver](https://github.com/datastax/java-driver) offers token-aware routing out of the box.  I would use that instead of trying to reinvent the wheel in Hector, especially since Hector uses the legacy Thrift API instead of [CQL](http://www.datastax.com/documentation/cql/3.0/webhelp/index.html).

Comment: For those seeing this and the other answer from jbellis to this question: these duplicates appear because I merged another question into this one.